# What does "DxD" in "Highschool DxD" stand for?

Tags: high-school-dxd

I have been following **High School DxD**'s anime and manga. However, there has been no explanation of what **DxD** in the title means so far.

Does anyone know what it stands for?

Comment: In Highschool DxD BorN opening it says "Dear x Dear"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As revealed in **Volume 16** of the light novel, DxD is the name of an anti-terrorism organization and has the meaning of the different factions which form the group:

> Devils, also a Dragon, and the word “Fallen” of a Fallen Angel—like downfall.

(In Japanese, Fallen Angel is [堕天使]【だてんし】, whose romaji *datenshi* starts with D)

Quoting from the novel:

> —Then Koneko-chan mutters.
>
> “—[D×D].”
>
> Everyone gazes at Koneko-chan’s muttering. Koneko-chan is surprised at
> having so much attention directed towards her. She then continues
> while feeling shy.
>
> “Well, since it’s a mixed team consisted of different beings, that’s
> how I felt……”
>
> Rias then asks.
>
> “What does the [D×D] stand for? Does it stand for being a Dragon of
> Dragon like Great Red?”
>
> “No, it can stand for Devils, also a Dragon, and the word “Fallen” of
> a Fallen Angel—like downfall.”
>
> Koneko-chan answers.
>
> I see, so it means [D×D] while pointing towards Devils, Dragons, and
> such.
>
> Sensei nods his head.

---

According to **Volume 6** of the light novel, DxD also stands for *Dragon of Dragons*, referring to the Great Red:

> “There are two dragons called the ‘Red Dragons’. One of them is the ancient dragon from Wales residing in you. Welsh Dragon. The Sekiryuutei. Hakuryuukou also comes from the same origin and the same myth. But there is one more ‘Red Dragon’. That is the Red-Dragon which is recorded in Revelation.”
>
> “Revelation……?”
>
> “The True God-Emperor of Red-Dragon. Apocalypse Dragon, the Great-Red. It’s the great dragon which is called the ‘True-Dragon’. It chooses to live in the dimensional gap and swims there for eternity. Today, we came here to confirm ‘that’. The field of Rating Game is inside a section in the dimensional gap by putting on a barrier. This time, Ophis’s true aim was to confirm that. Shalba’s plan was something which wasn’t important to us.”
>
> [...]
>
> That time, Vali showed the clearest eyes ever seen before.
>
> “The one I want to fight the most. **The Apocalypse Dragon Great-Red who is called [DxD], Dragon of Dragon.** –I want to become “The True God-Emperor of White-Dragon”. It won’t look good if the ‘white’ is a rank below the ‘Red’ when there is the ultimate-class for ‘Red’ right? That’s why I will become one. One day when I defeat Great-Red.”

Comment: Fallen Angel is written as 堕天使 and pronounced as Daten-shi, which is why fallen angels get bunched into the whole dragons and devils, in case anyone is wondering where the "D" is in DxD

Comment: @ton.yeung not that the hyphenation matters in anyway, but if anything it should be da-tenshi.

Comment: Add in that Issei's latest power up which combines Ddraig's power with Ophis and Great Red's is called DxD (read as Diabolos Dragon).

Answer (score 0):

The "DxD" in *High School DxD* stands for "Draw x Delete".

In the opening song of *High School DxD*, (I suggest listening to the one with lyrics in English) you can see in it that they do say the full form of "DxD".